# How to call a cronjob file in ubuntu

Tags: php, ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04, cron

I have a cron file which is located in `/var/www/html/mysite/cron/all.cronjobs`

How can I call this file? The file contains of cron tasks

```
17 1 * * *  /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/mysite/cron/file1.php
23 1 * * *  /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/mysite/cron/file2.php  
...
```

Should I call this file inside cron `crontab -e` ? Or should I set another cron to be called?

Any help please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your cron file a list of cron jobs you'd like to add (a crontab)?

If so you could put the file in `/etc/cron.d/` (or symlink it there), though be aware that this means it'll run as root.

To replace a users crontab with yours you can do

`crontab /var/www/html/mysite/cron/all.cronjobs`

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that your `all.crobjobs` file is formatted like a crontab, so one or more jobs defined, one per line with the time/period definitions.

You can't "call" this file - it's not executable as it is. The contents of it need to be added to your user's crontab, using `crontab -e` as you suggest. Just copy and paste in the contents of `all.cronjobs` and save it.